# Matlab: sorting a vector by the number of time each unique value occurs

Tags: matlab, unique, octave

We have p.e. `i = 1:25` iterations.
Each iteration result is a `1xlength(N)` cell array, where `0<=N<=25`.

```
iteration 1: 4     5     9    10     20     
iteration 2: 3     8     9    13     14      6
...
iteration 25:  1     2    3
```

We evaluate the results of all iterations to one matrix sorted according to frequency each value is repeated in descending order like this example:

```
Matrix=
  Columns 1 through 13
    16    22    19    25     2     5     8    14    17    21     3    12    13
     6     5     4     4     3     3     3     3     3     3     2     2     2
  Columns 14 through 23
    18    20     1     6     7     9    10    11    15    23
     2     2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Result explanation: Column 1: `N == 16` is present in 6 iterations, column 2: `N == 22` is present in 5 iterations etc.
If a number `N` isn't displayed (in that paradigm `N == 4`, `N == 24`) in any iteration, is not listed with frequency index of zero either.

I want to associate each iteration (`i`) to the first `N` it is displayed p.e. `N == 9` to be present only in first iteration `i = 1` and not in `i = 2` too, `N == 3` only to `i = 2` and not in `i = 25` too etc until all `i`'s to be unique associated to `N`'s.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way that uses a feature of `unique` (i.e. that it returns the index to the first value) that was introduced in R2012a

```
%# make some sample data
iteration{1} = [1 2 4 6];
iteration{2} = [1 3 6];
iteration{3} = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
nIter= length(iteration);

%# create an index vector so we can associate N's with iterations
nn = cellfun(@numel,iteration);
idx = zeros(1,sum(nn));
idx([1,cumsum(nn(1:end-1))+1]) = 1;
idx = cumsum(idx); %# has 4 ones, 3 twos, 6 threes

%# create a vector of the same length as idx with all the N's
nVec = cat(2,iteration{:});

%# run `unique` on the vector to identify the first occurrence of each N
[~,firstIdx] = unique(nVec,'first');

%# create a "cleanIteration" array, where each N only appears once
cleanIter = accumarray(idx(firstIdx)',firstIdx',[nIter,1],@(x){sort(nVec(x))},{});

cleanIter = 
    [1x4 double]
    [         3]
    [         5]

>> cleanIter{1}
ans =
     1     2     4     6
```

Comment: Thank you this approach is very educative @Jonas.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using `accumarray`. Explanations in the comments

```
% example data (from your question)
iteration{1} = [4     5     9    10     20  ];
iteration{2} = [3     8     9    13     14      6];
iteration{3} = [1     2    3];
niterations = length(iteration);

% create iteration numbers 
% same as Jonas did in the first part of his code, but using a short loop
for i=1:niterations
    idx{i} = i*ones(size(iteration{i}));
end

% count occurences of values from all iterations
% sort them in descending order
occurences = accumarray([iteration{:}]', 1);
[occ val] = sort(occurences, 1, 'descend');

% remove zero occurences and create the Matrix
nonzero = find(occ);
Matrix = [val(nonzero) occ(nonzero)]'

Matrix =

 3     9     1     2     4     5     6     8    10    13    14    20
 2     2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1


% find minimum iteration number for all occurences
% again, using accumarray with @min function
assoc = accumarray([iteration{:}]', [idx{:}]', [], @min);
nonzero = find(assoc);
result = [nonzero assoc(nonzero)]'

result =

 1     2     3     4     5     6     8     9    10    13    14    20
 3     3     2     1     1     2     2     1     1     2     2     1
```